# How to restrict date hierarchy to years in django administration?

Tags: python, django

I need to display some data from a table in django administration. Everything is set and working but I was wondering what I could do to restrict the date_hierarchy to years only. Not allowing it to show in detail for months and date.

Here's the view:

```py
class HistorySummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/history_summary_change_list.html'
    date_hierarchy = 'date_and_time'
    list_filter = (
        'device_type',
    )

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        response = super(HistorySummaryAdmin, self).changelist_view(
            request,
            extra_context=extra_context,
        )

        try:
            qs = response.context_data['cl'].queryset
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            return response

        metrics = {
            'views': Count("date_and_time"),
        }

        selectpart = {
            'week': "CONCAT(YEAR(DATE_ADD(date_and_time, INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(date_and_time) DAY)),'-',LPAD(WEEK(DATE_ADD(date_and_time, INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(date_and_time) DAY)),2,0))",        
        }

        response.context_data['summary'] = list(
            qs
            .extra(select=selectpart)
            .values('week')
            .annotate(**metrics)
            .order_by('-week')
        )

        summary_over_time = qs.extra(select=selectpart).values('week').annotate(**metrics).order_by('-views')
        high = summary_over_time.first()['views']
        low = summary_over_time.last()['views']
        summary_over_time = qs.extra(select=selectpart).values('week').annotate(**metrics).order_by('week')

        response.context_data['summary_over_time'] = [{
            'week': x['week'],
            'views': x['views'],
            'pct': x['views'] * 100 / high,
        } for x in summary_over_time]

        return response
```

And my template:

```
<div class="results">
    <h2> Views over time </h2>
    <div class="bar-chart-graph">
        <div class="bar-chart">
        {% for x in summary_over_time %}
            <div class="bar" style="height:{{x.pct}}%">
                <div class="bar-tooltip">
                    <p>{{x.week}}</p>
                    <p>{{x.views | default:0 }} views</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div class="text">
                <a href="#">Week</a>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th>
              <div class="text">
                <a href="#">Views</a>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for row in summary %}
          <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
            <td> {{ row.week }} </td>
            <td> {{ row.views | intcomma }} </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to let the user choose a year, but not a month.

Yes :
[image]

No :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I've solved the problem by myself. Here's how :

I created a filter from the SimpleListField class called DateYearFilter. Here's the code :

```
class DateYearFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'year'
    parameter_name = 'date_and_time'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        #Choices to propose are all the years from the start
        firstyear = History.objects.order_by('date_and_time').first().date_and_time.year #First year of the history
        currentyear = datetime.datetime.now().year  #Current year
        years = [] #Declaration of the list that'll contain the missing years
        for x in range(currentyear-firstyear):  #Fill the list with the missing years
            yearinloop = firstyear+x
            years.insert(0,(str(yearinloop),str(yearinloop)))
        years.insert(0,(str(currentyear),str(currentyear)))
        return years

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value(): #If a year is set, we filter by year else not
            return queryset.filter(date_and_time__year=self.value())
        else:
            return queryset
```

Then I removed the date hierarchy from the admin class and added this filter so it's kinda the same thing.
Here's the code :

```py
class HistorySummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/history_summary_change_list.html'
    #Filter by device type and by year, so the data are regrouped by year
    list_filter = ['device_type',DateYearFilter]
```

What's now displaying instead of the bar with the dates is :

[image: New filters]

I hope it'll help somebody that needs to do the same :)